# Proving that an expectation is finite

Tags: probability, expectation

> Let $X$ be a random variable such that there exists a $r \in (0,
>  \infty)$ where $E(|X|^r)<\infty$. Show that $E(|X|^l)<\infty$ for all
>    $l \in (0, \infty)$ and $l \le r$.

My attempt is like this: Fix $l \in (0, r]$. Then $|x|^l \le |x|^r$ for all $x$. So taking expectations, we have $E(|X|^l) \le E(|X|^r) < \infty$, and we are done.

However, I was given a hint where $|x|^l < |x|^r+1$ and then taking expectations yields $E(|X|^l) < E(|X|^r)+1 < \infty$. Why do we need to have a $+1$ here? Is my approach fine as well?

Comment: Note that $|x|^l\not\leq |x|^r$ for $x\in(0,1)$, but for such $x$ $|x|^l < 1$.

Comment: See Hölder's inequality.

Comment: @Mark Right, that makes sense. So is my following argument correct then? For $x \in (-1, 1)$, we have $|x|^l > |x|^r$ but $|x|^l < 1$ and for $x \notin (-1, 1)$, we have $|x|^l \le |x|^r$, so overall, we can say for all $x$, we have $|x|^l < |x|^r+1$. The rest follows from my opening post.